# Постоянные ссылки и редирект

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Я поменял постоянную ссылку с
`/%category%/%postname%/` на `/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%/`

Теперь не могу правильно настроить редирект.

Нашел и немного изменил функцию под свою ситуацию, но есть проблема. Функция срабатывает даже на главной странице и редиректит на первую запись на главной.

Мне нужно, чтобы функция срабатывала только при внешнем переходе по старой ссылке. А может сделать какую-нибудь дополнительную проверку, чтобы функция лишний раз не срабатывала.

Какие есть мысли?

```
function rudr_post_permalink( $url ){
$request_uri = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$the_slug = basename(parse_url($request_uri, PHP_URL_PATH));
$args = array(
  'name'        => $the_slug,
  'post_type'   => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
    
if( $my_posts ) :
  $post_url = get_post_permalink($my_posts[0]->ID);
  wp_redirect($post_url, 301);
  die();
endif;

}

add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'rudr_post_permalink');
```

Comment: Мысли такие, что ID в урле - большие приключения на седалище в будущем. Да и `category` там нафик не нужно. А по вопросу - если ранее не менял пермалинки, то ничего делать не нужно - ВП сам отредиректит.

Comment: какие могут быть последствия, вы уже не первый кто так говорит, но никто не внес конкретики о последствиях.

Comment: Никто не говорит - может потому что никто такого вопроса не задаёт? Но раз я не первый - может стоит всё же прислушаться?

Comment: Может) Но все таки какие последствия? Расскажите, буду благодарен.

Comment: Задавай отдельным вопросом. Таковы правила SО.

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кому будет нужно, сделал так.

```
function rudr_post_permalink($url)
{
    $request_uri = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $the_slug = basename(parse_url($request_uri, PHP_URL_PATH));

    if ($the_slug)
    {
        $args = array(
            'name' => $the_slug,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'numberposts' => 1
        );
        $my_posts = get_posts($args);

        if ($my_posts):
            $post_url = get_post_permalink($my_posts[0]->ID);
            wp_redirect($post_url, 301);
            die();
        endif;

    }
}

add_filter('template_redirect', 'rudr_post_permalink');
```